# How to convert a USB drive onto FAT12?

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive

I have a USB of 2GB and I want to make MS-DOS stuff on it, so I need to convert it on FAT12. I absolutely **don't** know how to do that, since FAT12 is a very old File System. Thank you for reading my post !

PS : Why do I post that on an UNIX forum ? Because I didn't saw a "File Systems" Stack Exchange site, and I only have a Mac OS 11 and a Debian 11 on my computer (no Windows).

Comment: MS-DOS should be able to work with FAT16. Why are you sure you can't do without the older FAT12?

Comment: I don't know, the disk image of my version of MS-DOS is formated in FAT12 so I guessed I must convert my USB in FAT12.

Comment: What version of MS-DOS are you interested in running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mkfs.vfat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.vfat.8.html) (from the `dosfstools` package on Debian) can create FAT12, all you need is `-F12` option when using it. FAT12 is limited to 32 MiB so you first need to create a 32 MiB (or smaller) partition on your drive  and then run `mkfs.vfat -F12 /dev/sdxY` to make FAT12 on it.

As mentioned in the comments, DOS should be able to work with FAT16 which should be better for you because you could use all 2 GiB of your USB drive. You can create FAT16 the same way with `mkfs.vfat` just use `-F16` instead of `-F12`.

Comment: Thanks ! It really helped me a lot !